# Cannot edit text inside a React Modal with State to Edit Task Title and Body

Tags: reactjs, forms, bootstrap-modal

I'm wondering if anyone else has had success editing text inside a Bootstrap React Modal and could share some wisdom. I'm using a Bootstrap React Modal to display data once the user clicks on the task title. The data is displaying beautifully, but the user cannot edit the data. The cursor changes to an editing cursor, but no amount of keyboard pounding gets an edit. I tried adding a Bootstrap React Form as you can see below. When I click on the "Save Changes" button, I get my toastify error.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import taskAPI from "../../utils/taskAPI";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./style.css";

function TaskModal({ onHide, onTaskUpdated, task }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [textBody, setTextBody] = useState("");
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);

  const notify = () => toast.warn("You cannot save an empty task!");

 const updateTask=(event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsPending(true);
    taskAPI
      .updateTask({ title, textBody })
      .then((response) => {
        response.setTitle("");
        response.setTextBody("");
      })
      .then((response) => {
        onTaskUpdated();
        setIsPending(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setIsPending(false);
        notify();
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={true} onHide={onHide}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="TaskTitleText">
                <Form.Control
                  className="TaskTitleText"
                  as="textarea"
                  size="lg"
                  rows="1"
                  value={task.title}
                  onChange={(event)=> setTitle(event.target.value)}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="TaskBodyText">
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                multiple
                value={task.textBody}
                onChange={(event)=> setTextBody(event.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            value={isPending ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
            onClick={updateTask}
          >
            Save Changes
            <ToastContainer />
          </Button>
          <Button variant="secondary"
           value={isPending ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
           onClick={onHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default TaskModal;
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to below, I have checked it and update the solutions with you.
It will perfectly works everytime.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import taskAPI from "../../utils/taskAPI";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import "./style.css";

function TaskModal({ onHide, onTaskUpdated, task }) {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(task.title || "");
  const [textBody, setTextBody] = useState(task.textBody || "");
  const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(false);

  const notify = () => toast.warn("You cannot save an empty task!");

 const updateTask=(event)=> {
    event.preventDefault();
    setIsPending(true);
    taskAPI
      .updateTask({ title, textBody })
      .then((response) => {
        response.setTitle("");
        response.setTextBody("");
      })
      .then((response) => {
        onTaskUpdated();
        setIsPending(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setIsPending(false);
        notify();
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={true} onHide={onHide}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>
            <Form>
              <Form.Group controlId="TaskTitleText">
                <Form.Control
                  className="TaskTitleText"
                  as="textarea"
                  size="lg"
                  rows="1"
                  value={title}
                  onChange={(event)=> setTitle(event.target.value)}
                />
              </Form.Group>
            </Form>
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="TaskBodyText">
              <Form.Control
                as="textarea"
                multiple
                value={textBody}
                onChange={(event)=> setTextBody(event.target.value)}
              ></Form.Control>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            value={isPending ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
            onClick={updateTask}
          >
            Save Changes
            <ToastContainer />
          </Button>
          <Button variant="secondary"
           value={isPending ? "Saving..." : "Submit"}
           onClick={onHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default TaskModal;
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are setting the `value` of your `Form.Control` to `task.textBody` and not `textBody`. `task.Textbody` is a prop that is passed into your element from the parent element, while `taskBody` is the local state (from `useState("")`) that you are actually updating in your `onChange` function.

You probably want to manage the state in a parent component, in which case you can pass down an `onChange` method that this component can call whenever the text changes.

Comment: Thank you! As you can tell, I'm new to React and this has really helped point me in the right direction. I will post when I get it solved:)